# grunt-contrib-jasmine and PhantomJS security

Tags: phantomjs, gruntjs

I'm getting an error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my-api.domain.com. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

when I try to run some async unit tests that query an API through grunt-contrib-jasmine, which in turn using PhantomJS. I see that the command line version of PhantomJS does have a 'web-security' options. Can I control how grunt-contrib-jasmine uses PhantomJS to include this option and disable the cross-domain security?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass options to phantomjs similarly to how you would on the command line, e.g.

The following options may help, but more can be found at the [phantomjs docs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference#command-line-options)

```
jasmine : {
  your_task : {
    options : {
      '--web-security' : false,
      '--local-to-remote-url-access' : true,
      '--ignore-ssl-errors' : true
    }
  }
}
```