# Jasmine and PhantomJS error NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs

I try to use phantomJS with Jasmine. But my fixtures can't be load because an error

Error: JSONFixture could not be loaded: assets/backend/fixtures/json/fr.json (status: error, message: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101)

I can see here I must add option to phantomJS for disable cross-server security.

[Phantom JS synchronous AJAX request : NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913170/phantom-js-synchronous-ajax-request-network-err-xmlhttprequest-exception-101)

or here:

[grunt-contrib-jasmine and PhantomJS security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826203/grunt-contrib-jasmine-and-phantomjs-security)

But I don't know where to pass this options because phantomJS is called automatically when call:

bundle exec rake spec:javascript

or

bundle exec Guard -g frontend

So you can see I use Guard too but I think it's the next step.

Thanks to read and best regards

Comment: Same problem here. Find a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Add the below to your `jasmine.yml` file

`phantom_options: --web-security=no`

Comment: I don't have the code anymore so if this comment help someone let me know i'll validate the answer.